# python extract value from JSON of gmaps distance matrix

Tags: python, json, google-maps, python-3.x

I am using Gmaps Distance Matrix to get a value distance from given point of origin and destination.

```
ddist = gmaps.distance_matrix (Origin, Destination)
```

and get this result:

```
{'status': 'OK', 'origin_addresses': ['Depok, Depok City, West Java, Indonesia'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'status': 'OK', 'duration': {'value': 4366, 'text': '1 hour 13 mins'}, 'distance': {'value': 46143, 'text': '46.1 km'}}]}], 'destination_addresses': ['North Jakarta, North Jakarta City, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia']}
```

I want to extract ['distance']['value'] from above JSON.

This is what I have for now:

```
for who in ddistt.keys():
ddist = json.loads(ddistt)
print('For %s: "value":' %who, ddist['rows']['element']['distance']['value'])
```

And return to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/src/distance.py", line 17, in <module>
    ddist = json.loads(ddistt)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the returned value is already a dictionary so you don't need to call `json.loads`. Just do:

```
>>> ddistt = {'status': 'OK', 'origin_addresses': ['Depok, Depok City, West Java, Indonesia'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'status': 'OK', 'duration': {'value': 4366, 'text': '1 hour 13 mins'}, 'distance': {'value': 46143, 'text': '46.1 km'}}]}], 'destination_addresses': ['North Jakarta, North Jakarta City, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia']}
>>> ddistt["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"]
46143
```